# Installing Numpy and Biopython

Tags: python, numpy, biopython

I have been using Python 3.3 and have been successfully using Biopython. After much time, I realized I had to install python 3.2 to install numpy. However now I can't find a biopython download for python 3.2.

What do I need to do to be able to access both of these modules?

Thank you

Comment: Why did you need to install Python 3.2 to install numpy? It's worked on 3.3 since before 3.3 was officially released, and it even has binary installs (Christoph Gohlke's Windows packages, distro packages, community-submitted installers, wheels) if you can't figure out how to set up source builds.

Comment: Meanwhile, what platform are you using, and how did you install `biopython` for 3.3?

Comment: I was unable to find an install package for 3.3. Can you provide a link? I'm using windows 7, and I installed biopython at the following link: http://biopython.org/wiki/Download

Comment: @Malonge I think the same package should work fine.

Comment: @VivekRai: I doubt it. If so, why would they have separate 3.3 and 3.4 packages?

Comment: @Malonge: How did you install numpy for 3.2? How do you want to install it for 3.3? Have you even looked at the [getting numpy](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) and [installing the stack](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) docs? `pip install numpy` works; there are even wheels. The [official repo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.0/) has a 3.3 Windows installer (and not a 3.2). [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) has a 3.3 Windows installer. I can't find any official or reputable place that has 3.2 but not 3.3…

Comment: Looks like I was able to find a numpy package for 3.3, but now I can only import it directly from the python interpreter, but not from IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Biopython download page: https://biopython.org/wiki/Download
"Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, or 3.6 or PyPy, including the Python development header files like python.h"

and the official installation doc: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html
"As of Biopython 1.62 we officially support Python 3, specifically Python 3.3. Python 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2 will not be supported."

To use biopython you have to use one of the following python versions: v2.7, v3.4, v3.5, v3.6, (v3.7 will be supported in release 1.73: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/NEWS.rst#in-progress-not-yet-released-biopython-173)